# for which values of $\theta$ does this equation $x_{n+1}=\cos(\theta)x^2_{n}-\sin(\theta)x^2_{n-1}$ have bounded solutions?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, difference-equations, nash-equilibrium

I would like to investigate the global behavior of the following equation :

$$x_{n+1}=Ax^2_{n}-Bx^2_{n-1}$$

where $A(\theta)= \cos(\theta)$ and $B(\theta) =\sin(\theta)$  are nonnegative parameters and $x_{-1}$, $x_0$ are nonnegative with $x_{-1}+x_{0}>0$. Here is my question:

- For which values of $\theta$ does the equation below have bounded solutions?
  $$x_{n+1}=\cos(\theta)x^2_{n}-\sin(\theta)x^2_{n-1}$$

Note : $\theta$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, $n=0,1,2\cdots$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Whenever $\cos \theta > \sin \theta$, the point $(x,x)$ is fixed where $x = 1/(\cos \theta - \sin \theta)$. So that gives a bounded solution half of the time.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer :thank you ,does it studied before ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran a small computation: The following plot is created as follows:
For each point $r(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, I use $x_{-1} = 0$, $x_0 = r$
as initial values, and $\theta$ as the parameter.

The white area is where the iterations is less than $2$ (bounded), the first 20 iterations. As we see, a small circle around the origin is white, meaning that there are small initial values that is bounded for every $\theta$. Now, this is not a proof, but the picture suggests this.

Changing the cut-off to 40 iterations does not change the picture much.

[image: Plot]

EDIT: I think I have a proof of the statement.

Let $r=1/\sqrt{2}$. If $x_{-1},x_0 \leq r$, then the sequence is bounded for all $\theta$.

*Proof:* $|\cos(\theta)x_{n-1}^2 - \sin(\theta)x_{n}^2| \leq r^2(|\cos \theta|+|\sin \theta|) \leq r^2 \sqrt{2} \leq 1/\sqrt{2}$, and the statement follows from induction.

```
ValueFrom[x_, y_] := Module[{func, xf, xfp, iterTot, t, r, cc, sc},
   t = Arg[x + I y];
   r = Abs[x + I y];

   cc = Cos[t];
   sc = Sin[t];

   func[{xn_, xp_, i_}] := {xp, cc*xp^2 - sc*xn^2, i + 1}; 

   {xf, xfp, iterTot} = 
    NestWhile[func, {0, r, 0}, Abs[#[[2]]] < 2 && #[[3]] < 20 &];
   iterTot
   ];

DensityPlot[ValueFrom[x, y], {x, -2.0, 2.0}, {y, -2.0, 2.0},
 PlotPoints -> {150, 150}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
```

Comment: Thank you for this vizualisation , then for every theta there are a few bounded solution but how I can proof it ?

Comment: No idea, but if you are lucky, there is some $r$ such that if the initial values are less than $r$, then all numbers in the sequence are less than this $r$...

Comment: I added a proof.

Comment: alexanderson , thank you very much , I ask you if the below difference equation was studied before ?

Comment: @ZeraouliaKheireddine: I have no idea if it has been considered before...

Comment: :the main result from your proof is :if the parameters of any difference equations as the below form are bounded function then all solutions of it are bounded .

Comment: @ZeraouliaKheireddine: Exactly. As long as the initial values are less than $1/\sqrt{2}$ in absolute value, the entire sequence is bounded, independent of $\theta$.

Comment: Every ball centered at $0$ with radius at most $1/(|A|+|B|)$ is stable by the dynamics. For every $\theta$, $1/(|A(\theta)|+|B(\theta)|)\leqslant1/\sqrt2$. For every starting point such that $x_{-1}^2+x_0^2\lt1/2$, $x_n\to0$ at least geometrically fast.

Comment: @ per Alexandersson, if \theta =\pi/4 , what about equilibrum point ?

Comment: What do you mean by equilibrium point? You mean attracting fixed point?

Comment: yeah, i meant the attracting fixed point

Comment: yes, i meant the stability of attractive point